# Python Scheduler - "Process finished" after first job, wont run following jobs

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scrapy

I implemented a web-crawler using Python and Scrapy (https://scrapy.org/).

There are three different processes which need to run successively. The first one writes profile keys to a MongoDB collection, the second one crawls all subdomains for a given profile and writes them in another collection, and the third one writes specific profile data to a `SQL` database.

Now I want to run these processes automatically. I looked at the module **Schedule** (https://github.com/dbader/schedule, https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and wrote the following code:

```
import schedule
import time
from scrapy import cmdline
from scrapers.scrapy_new_users.helpers.dataAggregator import DataAggregator


def run_key_fetcher():
    print("Running key_fetcher")
    command = "scrapy crawl fetch_profile_keys ".split()
    cmdline.execute(command)


def run_profile_scraper():
    print("Running profile_scraper")
    command = ("scrapy crawl fetch_profiles "
               "-a login_user=user"
               "-a login_password=password").split()
    cmdline.execute(command)


def run_data_aggregator():
    print("Running data_aggregator")
    data_aggregator = DataAggregator()
    data_aggregator.parse()


schedule.every().day.at("1:00").do(run_key_fetcher)
schedule.every().day.at("2:00").do(run_profile_scraper)
schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(run_data_aggregator)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

When running this code, the first job gets started at the given time and I get a `Process finished with exit code 0`. After that the scheduler stops and the other jobs don't run.

I suspect that this is the normal behaviour for "Process finished", but is there any way around it?
Or should i use some different scheduling module?

I am not deploying the spiders via scrapyd, because my third process is not a spider.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this part of Scrapy documentation:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

Specifically the part where it says: running the spiders sequentially by chaining the deferreds.

What you can do is chain both spiders and data export script into one runner script. Than use the python scheduler module to call that script periodically.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapers.scrapy_new_users.helpers.dataAggregator import DataAggregator

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider1)
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider2)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
data_aggregator = DataAggregator()
data_aggregator.parse()
```